# Problems manipulating a Carbon date object in PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, php-carbon

I am having problems manipulating a Carbon date object (`$subscription->updated_at`):

```
$thisDate = $subscription->updated_at->date;
$thisDate = Date($graphDateFormat, $thisDate);
```

Results in `Unknown getter 'date'`

```
$thisDate = $subscription->updated_at;
$thisDate = Date($graphDateFormat, $thisDate);
```

Results in `date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given`

```
var_dump($subscription->updated_at);
```

Results in:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)[292]
  public 'date' => string '2013-08-21 17:05:19' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

How can I use a Carbon date inside the Date() function?

Comment: try `$subscription->updated_at->toDateTimeString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$subscription->updated_at->timestamp` to get the UNIX timestamp, which you can pass to `date`. It might be easier to use the `format()` method to format the date directly in the Carbon object:

```
$thisDate = subscription->updated_at->format($graphDateFormat);
```

Comment: $subscription is an object that has 2 Carbon dates, `created_at` and `updated_at` - should I be using `$subscription->updated_at->format($graphDateFormat);`??

Comment: Yes, sorry about that - got that mixed up in my answer. The update should match your code now.